# Group records on activeadmin resource index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, grouping, activeadmin

I have 2 resources - Shelf and Book, where each Shelf has many Books.

Is there any way to groups books (on Book index page) by Shelf? Specifically I would like to have Books sorted by Shelf and whenever Shelf changes, I would like to indicate that on the books list (inserting a h3 title with new shelf name between books on one shelf and books on the other)

I am using rails 3.2 and activeadmin 0.6.0.

Answer (score 6):

using ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre2 on Rails 4.2.5.2, it turned out to be quite simple. the solution is essentially only 20 lines of a custom ActiveAdmin view class.

> note the file names on the first line as a hint where to put the code or make additions/changes to existing files.

```rb
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths << config.root.join('lib')
  end
end
```

```rb
# models/book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shelf

  def shelf_name
    shelf.name
  end
end
```

```rb
# admin/books.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Book do
  index as: :grouped_table, group_by_attribute: :shelf_name do
    # columns
  end
end
```

```rb
# lib/active_admin/views/index_as_grouped_table.rb
require 'active_admin/views/index_as_table'

module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class IndexAsGroupedTable < IndexAsTable

      def build(page_presenter, collection)
        if group_by_attribute = page_presenter[:group_by_attribute]
          collection.group_by(&group_by_attribute).sort.each do |group_name, group_collection|
            h3 group_name
            super page_presenter, group_collection
          end
        else
          super
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

let me explain what the fuck happens in `index_as_grouped_table.rb`:

the class `IndexAsGroupedTable` extends ActiveAdmin's `IndexAsTable` class and overrides the `build` method to add grouping functionality.
in your `admin/books.rb` file, in the index macro, you define an additional option `:group_by_attribute` which names the attribute name on the `Book` class by which to group.
if that attribute is not provided, it falls back to `IndexAsTable`'s behavior.
if that attribute is provided, it'll `group_by` the collection by that attribute, `sort` the hash and run a block with each `group_name` and `group_collection` from that hash, printing an `<h3>` with the `group_name` and then just calls `IndexAsTable`'s `build` method (`super`) to display the standard table.

as you see, only the groups are sorted and an h3 added to the page. everything else works like the standard index table.

> note: this does not involve additional sql for the grouping. this uses ruby's [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method of the `Enumerable` class. thus, it may be slow if you have many rows in the collection.

for the most current version and/or forks go to my [my gist on github](https://gist.github.com/glaszig/f51ffee2b71ab66edcc2).

**credits for the approach go to [ariejan de vroom](https://ariejan.net/2007/01/12/rails-group-results-by-week-using-group_by/).**

Comment: for me it worked, but grouped rows only for current page

Comment: okliv, it works for me on any page of a paginated resource index.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a Custom Page

http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/10-custom-pages.html

1. By passing ordered @books in Active Admin controller
2. And then using table_for in content block (maybe a new table for each shelf? Or a shelf search field at the top. 
   http://blog.agile-pandas.com/2011/07/06/activeadmin-beyond-the-basics

:)